# How to change domain name by .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a domain eg: `abc.com.` While displaying news the url will be `abc.com/news.php?news=xyz`. And i want to change the url to something like `news.abc.com/xyz`.

Is it possible via .htaccess

Comment: did you think about solve it by virtual hosts?

Comment: i have no idea that it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.php?%1=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code in htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news.php?news=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```